# SQL Strategies for detecting what is causing a lock / long query

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, database-performance, dapper

I have a query against an Azure SQL database that occasionally results in the following:

[image]

If there aren't many users, this doesn't happen.  But if there are, this happens regularly - the query takes a very long time to complete and my DTU percentage is almost off the charts.

How do I determine what is causing this?

Some general info:

- I'm using dapper as an ORM in some portions of the application
- I'm using EF in other areas
- When it hangs, it hangs for >30sec.  Rarely is 1s < time < 30s
- The dapper query that hangs is below, where `XXXX` is a list of about 2,500 item IDs in both cases:
- It seems like users with a small set of `XXXX` Ids don't EVER hit this issue.  The retrieval of `XXXX` is not ever an issue - but using a large `XXXX` seems to aggravate performance sometimes.
- [User] is indexed on UserId (PK), and LastOnline

Code:

```
 select USERID, USERNAME, NICKNAME, BIRTHDATE, LASTONLINE 
  from [User]  
  where AccountDisabled <> 1 and Banned <> 1 and 
     (ABOUTME <> '' OR ProvidedPhoto = 1) and 
     USERID <> @userId  and ProvidedPhoto = 1  AND 
     USERID IN (-1)  AND USERID NOT IN (-1)  
     AND USERID NOT IN (XXXX) UNION ALL  
          select * from (select USERID, USERNAME, NICKNAME, BIRTHDATE, LASTONLINE from [User] where 
                AccountDisabled <> 1 and 
                Banned <> 1 and (ABOUTME <> '' OR ProvidedPhoto = 1) and 
                USERID <> @userId  and ProvidedPhoto = 1  AND USERID NOT IN (-1)  
                AND USERID NOT IN (XXXX)  AND USERID NOT IN (-1)  
                order by LastOnline asc offset 0 rows fetch next + 20 rows only)          
     as dt
```

I'm a bit new to the world of performance forensics... any advice would be awesome.

Update - Execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: Does the mapper map to a stored procedure with parameters or does it generate sql on the fly?

Comment: It generates SQL - https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: As you already mentioned, it generates SQL, so, first, it is not pre-compiled as stored procedures are. Hence, it tends to take more time when compared to a stored procedure. Second, Could you please share Indexes of table [User], if any. Third, try replacing USERID NOT IN with NOT EXISTS. It should help.

Comment: @AkankshaSingh thanks.  User is indexed on PK UserId and LastOnline.

Comment: @AkankshaSingh I'm having trouble converting NOT IN with NOT EXISTS.  Bit of a SQL novice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things you can try:

1. See if you can create a stored procedure to return your required list by passing @UserID as parameter. Call this stored procedure instead of generating query every-time.
2. Replace NOT IN with NOT EXISTS as below. First check if this helps. It very much depends on the values in USERID column.

   ```
   SELECT USERID,USERNAME,NICKNAME,BIRTHDATE,LASTONLINE
   FROM [User]
   WHERE AccountDisabled <> 1
   AND Banned <> 1
   AND (
   ABOUTME <> ''
   OR ProvidedPhoto = 1
   )
   AND USERID <> @userId
   AND ProvidedPhoto = 1
   AND USERID IN (- 1)  --How will these two conditions ever be true together?
   AND USERID NOT IN (- 1) --Be sure about your conditions
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT USERID FROM [USER] U2 WHERE U1.USERID = U2.USERID)

   UNION ALL

   SELECT *
   FROM (  SELECT USERID,USERNAME,NICKNAME,BIRTHDATE,LASTONLINE
   FROM [User] U1
   WHERE AccountDisabled <> 1
   AND Banned <> 1
   AND (
       ABOUTME <> ''
       OR ProvidedPhoto = 1
       )
   AND USERID <> @userId
   AND ProvidedPhoto = 1
   AND USERID NOT IN (- 1)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT USERID FROM [USER] U2 WHERE U1.USERID = U2.USERID)
   -- AND USERID NOT IN (- 1) WHY AGAIN??
   ORDER BY LastOnline ASC offset 0 rows FETCH NEXT + 20 rows ONLY
   ) AS dt
   ```
3. You may also think of creating NON-CLUSTERED Indexes on the other columns you have in WHERE clause. Could you please show execution plan of the query as well? (How: In SQL Query editor, press CTRL+M and then execute your query. You will get an execution plan along with the results.)

Comment: Updated!  Thank you so much for this - trying now.  Also - I'm a bit confused - the XXXX was literally a list of Ids, like this: `USERID NOT IN 
(9590, 10916, 11231, 9421.... 2,500 items... 2283, 4422)` - I don't see the mapping here.

Comment: If theses IDs are list, put them in a temp table before coming to this query. And then write the NOT EXISTS query over that temp table.